# Dynamically getting Properties in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, properties-file

I want to keep a mailing functionality in my shell script, where I can dynamically decide who are the mail recipients; I have defined a prop file which looks like this:

## test.properties

```
servers=primserver1#secserver1
mailrecipients=XXX@abc.com
primserver1-mailrecipients=abc@xxx.com
```

Now, I want to implement the script in such a way, that if I have property servername-mailrecipients in the property file, then the mail should be sent to these recipients, otherwise mail should be sent to the ids in mailrecipients property.

this is shell script I am writing:

## test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script for establishing connection between DMZ server and EMS server

scriptsroot=/app/test
cd "$scriptsroot/properties/test" || exit
if [ -f "test.properties" ]; then
   echo "Loading Property File: test.properties"
   # shellcheck source=/dev/null
   . ./test.properties
else
   echo "Property File: test.properties does not exist"
   exit;
fi
destservers=(${servers//#/ })
echo "${destservers[0]}; ${destservers[1]}"
echo "$mailrecipients"
echo "${${destservers[0]}-mailrecipients}"
```

However, I am getting following exception:

## Output

```
Loading Property File: test.properties
./test.properties: line 3: primems1-mailrecipients=abc@xxx.com: command not found
primems1; secems1
XXX@abc.com
test.sh: line 23: ${${destservers[0]}-mailrecipients}: bad substitution
```

Please provide some suggestions

Comment: You cannot have a shell variable with - character inside.

Comment: Variable names cannot contain `-`, change it to `_`, regarding `${${destservers[0]}-mailrecipients}`, you just can't do that.

Comment: Still getting error: test.sh: line 19: ${${destservers[0]}_mailrecipients}: bad substitution

Comment: @user2037281 Because it is illegal code, you can't do dynamic variables like that.

Comment: please suggest alternate ways to implement it

Comment: I am thinking of putting all props in a map like structure, and then getting the value based on the keyname generated dynamically